# Accessing array value is null

Tags: php

Hello I have decoded a json string that I sent to my server and Im trying to get the values from him.

My problem is that I cant get the values from the inner arrays.

This is my code:

```
<?php

    $post = file_get_contents('php://input');

    $arrayBig = json_decode($post, true);

    foreach ($arrayBig as $array)
    {


    $exercise = $array['exercise'];

    $response["exercise"] = $exercise;
    $response["array"] = $array;

    echo json_encode($response);


    }

?>
```

When I get the answer from my `$response` I get this values:

```
{"exercise":null,"array":[{"exercise":"foo","reps":"foo"}]}
```

Why is `$array['exercise']` null if I can see that is not null in the array

Thanks.

Comment: You should do a `var_dump($arrayBig)`. You'll probably see you have another array in your array.

Comment: I suggest you enable `display_errors` and set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL`. You have an undefined index error for `$array['exercise']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the result of `$response['array']`, it looks like `$array` is actually this

```
[['exercise' => 'foo', 'reps' => 'foo']]
```

that is, an associative array nested within a numeric one. You should probably do some value checking before blindly assigning values but in the interest of brevity...

```
$exercise = $array[0]['exercise'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of the `[{...}]` you are getting an array in an array when you decode your `array` key.

So:

```
$exercise = $array['exercise'];
```

Should be:

```
$exercise = $array[0]['exercise'];
```

See the [example here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/SvHl1l).